# Creating table to specify compression option

Tags: sql-server

I am using this hard-to-understood syntax (sorry I am new to Sql server :))

```
CREATE TABLE   
    [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] table_name   
    [ AS FileTable ]  
    ( {   <column_definition>   
        | <computed_column_definition>    
        | <column_set_definition>   
        | [ <table_constraint> ]   
        | [ <table_index> ] }  
          [ ,...n ]    
          [ PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ( system_start_time_column_name   
             , system_end_time_column_name ) ]  
      )  
    [ ON { partition_scheme_name ( partition_column_name )   
           | filegroup   
           | "default" } ]   
    [ TEXTIMAGE_ON { filegroup | "default" } ]   
    [ FILESTREAM_ON { partition_scheme_name   
           | filegroup   
           | "default" } ]  
    [ WITH ( <table_option> [ ,...n ] ) ]  
[ ; ]
```

and the table option I would want to ask is

```
<table_option> ::=  
{  
    [DATA_COMPRESSION = { NONE | ROW | PAGE }  
      [ ON PARTITIONS ( { <partition_number_expression> | <range> }   
      [ , ...n ] ) ]]  
.....
```

How does it mean I can format my T-Sql script  ?

For example,

```
CREATE TABLE Black_Cowgirl_tb
([name] int not null, [location] varchar(50) not null, [SheCanCook] bit not null, [SheCanRideAHorse] bit not null,... ) WITH 
(
DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE ON PARTITIONS (1), 
DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW ON PARTITIONS (2, 4, 6 TO 8), 
DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE ON PARTITIONS (3, 5)
)
```

Would you please enlist all possible ways to format this with data compression option ? I'd like to learn a lot but never could I have a chance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table_option> ::=  
{  
    [DATA_COMPRESSION = { NONE | ROW | PAGE }  
      [ ON PARTITIONS ( { <partition_number_expression> | <range> }   
      [ , ...n ] ) ]]  

.....
```

> Would you please enlist all possible ways to format this with data compression option ?

values in square brackets are mandatory..so below are mandatory

```
data_Compression,ON PARTITIONS,..n
```

values in flower brackets means you will need to select one of them.

In this case

```
{ NONE | ROW | PAGE }
```

can be read as  None or Row or Page..

so finally

data_Compression =
none or row or page
on 
partitions(1) or partitions (1-2)

Answer (score 0):

Your example is wrong because your table is not partitioned, so if you get any error it's not due to incorrect use of `compression` option but because the table you are creating has no partitions at all.

Here you can find plenty of examples:
[Creating Compressed Tables and Indexes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449(v=sql.105).aspx)

Example C is your case:

```
CREATE TABLE PartitionTable1 
(col1 int, col2 varchar(max))
ON myRangePS1 (col1) 
WITH 
(
  DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW ON PARTITIONS (1),
  DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE ON PARTITIONS (2 TO 4)
);
GO
```